# How to retrieve and check the browser language preference

Tags: c#, http

I want to retrieve the language preference of the browser, which is set in the settings-language-language preferences. I would like to check whether the language is set to German or English. With the following code, I can override the language preference and set it to 'de' or 'en', but how can I actually get the language?

When I use `var r = request.Headers.GetValues("Accept-Language");` the header is checked, but this may not correspond to the browser's language preference. Also if the header is not set by default, then I would get the error `"The given header was not found"`.

How can I retrieve the browser's language preference without removing and setting it? This would allow me to check the language preference and change it if necessary. For example, if the preference is 'de', then I will change it to 'en'.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
    
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://www.google.de/?hl=de");
        request.Headers.Remove("Accept-Language");
        request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "de");
        
        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);       
        Console.WriteLine("Erste response " + response.StatusCode);               
    
        var request1 = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://www.google.de/?hl=de");
        request1.Headers.Remove("Accept-Language");
        request1.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en");
    
        var response1 = await client.SendAsync(request1);      
        Console.WriteLine("Erste response2 " +  response1.StatusCode);               
    }
}
```

**Edited:**

So something like this? @padeso

```
        var newLang = {{language: 'en-US'}};
        
        Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'language', {{ value: newLang.language, configurable: true }});
        Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'languages', {{ get: () => [newLang.language], configurable: true }});
```

Comment: The settings for a HTTPRequestMessage and a Browser are obtained from a common area in the User Temp Space.  The settings should be the same.

Comment: In that code the app acts as a client, so there’s no browser involved; the language preference is up to you. If you were dealing with a browser, you’d probably need client code to tell you its language setting, possibly by reading it from `Navigator.language` and passing it as a parameter to the server request.